# Scheduling a script in R with encoding

Tags: r, encoding, r-taskscheduler

I have a script in R, task.R, that reads in a .csv file, does  bunch of calculations and writes a new .csv file with the final data. I'm having trouble with special characters (Icelandic), e.g. æ, á, ú etc.
As an example, when I source task.R, Ára becomes Ã¡ra. If I use `source("task.R", encoding =  "UTF-8")` everything is fine.

I want to use the taskscheduleR package in R which basically source the task.R script. But because of the encoding problem, I have to create new script e.g. source_task.R with only one line of code: `source("task.R", encoding =  "UTF-8")`.
Is there any way to use the taskscheduleR package and somehow use encoding = "UTF-8" without having to create new script like source_task.R?

Comment: Would it help if you could modify the Icelandic characters to something more standard? There are functions like this that could be applied: ```stringi::stri_trans_general(x, "Latin-ASCII"))```

Comment: How do you read your csv-file in the first place? you might want to look at the `locale`-argument of the `readr::read_csv`-function.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the R file with Notepad, and save it with ANSI encoding.

This is a ridiculous solution, but it works.

Did you happen to find any other solutions?